# What is the right public key to verify a gtoken JWT from Google Identity Toolkit?

Tags: perl, x509, sha256, jwt, google-identity-toolkit

I am trying to verify the signature of the JSON Web Token "gtoken" that is returned by [Google Identity Toolkit](https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/web/).

However, it appears that the "signature" is 256 bytes but the public keys in the certificates found at https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs are only 128 bytes. Thus I get the error "Signature longer than key".

I'm using this Perl code:

```
use JSON;
use CGI;
use LWP::Simple;
use Crypt::OpenSSL::X509;
use Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA;
use MIME::Base64;

my $cgi = CGI->new();
my $json = JSON->new();

my $gtoken = $cgi->cookie('gtoken');

my ($header64, $body64, $signature64) = split(/\./, $gtoken, 3);
my $signed64 = "$header64.$body64";

$signature64 =~ s/\-/+/g;
$signature64 =~ s/\_/\//g;
my $m = length($signature64) % 4;
$signature64.="==" if($m == 2);
$signature64.="=" if($m == 3);
my $signature = decode_base64($signature64);
# Note that length($signature) == 256 here.

my $certs = $json->decode(get("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs"));
foreach my $cert (values %$certs) {
    eval {
        my $x509 = Crypt::OpenSSL::X509->new_from_string( $cert );
        my $rsa_pub = Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA->new_public_key($x509->pubkey());
        # Note that $rsa_pub->size() == 128 here.
        $rsa_pub->use_sha256_hash();
        $rsa_pub->verify($signed64, $signature);
    };
    warn $@ if $@;
}
```

Is there somewhere else I should look for a 2048 bit (256 byte) key used by google to sign JWTs for Google Identity Toolkit? Or is there a way to verify a 256 byte signature with a 128 byte public key? Or am I extracting the public key from the cert incorrectly? The fact that the signature is 256 bytes implies that the public key I use to verify the signature should also be 256 bytes as far as I can tell.

I also tried using the JSON::WebToken CPAN module but had the same problem with the key being shorter than the signature.

Comment: ***Always*** `use strict` and `use warnings`, especially before asking for help with your code. What you do in private is up to you, but please at least *appear* to have made an effort before writing a question here.

Comment: Meh, I cut and pasted from a longer script. I always use strict and use warnings. I've tried implementing this thing a dozen times in a dozen different ways including different languages. The problem here is not about the language it is about the 256 byte signature vs. the 128 byte public keys. The code is just for reference. 

I also didn't include the #! line or the content type header output or any number of other details that I thought distracted from the point I was making. But I did test the script as posted.

Comment: I mean it's not as if you could run this script trivially anyway. You'd need to set up Google Identity Toolkit and get yourself a gtoken cookie set. That takes a bit of doing, so I'm not looking for code review, I'm looking for someone who already knows the crypto steps needed to verify the signature on a Google-signed id token JWT. 

I read through the source code on the google libraries for a few different languages. Everything seems to suggest that you should do exactly what I'm doing above. So I wonder if I'm using the wrong crypto algorithm or getting the wrong keys.

Answer (score 1):

Google provides the gitkit library ported to various languages, and it has (at least for the node.js version which I use) a method for retrieving the public key handily from a common uri. Perl doesn't seem to be one of the languages, so I suggest that you get the Python version and try to mimic it the Perl way.

Check here for API reference and the uri from which the gitgit library gets the public key: https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/web/reference/relyingparty/getPublicKeys.

Check here for the Python quick-start app. It's got the link to the library: https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/web/quickstart/python.

Good luck.